# In Selenium how to handle this kind of multi select dropdown which contains checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down as shown in snap below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Per0.png)

I have a drop down as shown in snap below

enter image description here

I Need to handle the multiselect by clicking on the checkbox corresponding to the sector. I am fetching data from excel. Right now I have written code to click on the arrow in the drop down and then click on the corresponding checkbox. I need a better solution to handle multiple selection like this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share relevant code, HTML in text format (or link to page), error stack trace etc.

Comment: Can you share URL?